# Going from droplet flying through the air to ending up in the pneumocytes in the alveoli. How does SARS-CoV-2 do it?

Tags: coronavirus

There was a Q and A held with George Gao, the head of the Chinese CDC, published in the most recent issue of Science, where he suggests that the data support droplets as being the main mode of transmission in the community. Masks and social distancing, of course, ameliorate this mode of spread.

Droplets can be generated simply by speaking. And they can be flung at fairly high speed potentially landing in the posterior pharynx of another person.

Once the virus infects cells of the mucosa, say in the posterior pharynx, are the virus particles that are produce there aerosolized by the passing air flow? Once the particles are in the form of an aerosol, they can reach the alveoli. I can't imagine droplets being able to reach the alveoli directly.

Are there other mucosal surfaces which play a role, like the nose?

And what about the eye? How does that lead to spread to the lungs? Viremia?

I apologize for the multiple questions in one. But they are related.

Comment: I think answered by https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/actually-what-is-the-main-way-covid-19-spreads

Comment: Very similar questions but not exactly duplicates. The question about the eyes in particular.